# How to replace current dropdown items on click

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have a dropdown with some items and I'm trying to replace them when I click the button on the dropdown. I'm trying to replace `menuItems` with `newMenuItems` on click. Here is the code I have

```
const [data, setData] = React.useState(menuItems);

const menuItems = [
    { value: 'pdf', label: t('dashboardAsPDF'), group: 'image' },
    { value: 'png', label: t('dashboardAsPNG'), group: 'image' },
    { value: 'ecsv', label: t('exportSelection'), group: 'csv' },
];

const newMenuItems = [
    { value: 'csv', label: t('facebookCSV'), group: 'csv' },
    { value: 'gcsv', label: t('googleAdsCSV'), group: 'csv' },
];

const handleCSV = () => {
  //replace menu items logic goes here
};

return (
       <div key={'ExportMenu'}>
                {data.map((d: Item, index: number) => (
                    <StyledMenuItem value={d.value} selected={d.value === value} key={index}>
                        {d.value.toString().length > 1 ? (
                            <Label onClick={d.value === 'ecsv' ? () => handleCSV() : () => isCheckboxChecked(d.value.toString())}>{d.label}</Label>
                        ) : (
                                <Label key={'label'}>{d.label}</Label>
                            )}
                    </StyledMenuItem>
                ))}
            </div>
```

So, I'm trying to add the replacement logic to the `handleCSV` function, but I'm not sure how to do this. An example will be appreciated!

Comment: I am a bit confused as to what needs to be replaced? `menuItems` with `newMenuItems`? or something else?

Comment: yes, sorry, I've updated the question

Comment: alright, its a bit clearer now, where does `data.map` come from? Where do you get `data` from ? Since this is what renders the items I suppose?

Comment: The updated question, data is state, which is menuItems by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to utilize the second destructured paramater from `useState` called `setData`, like this:

```
const handleCSV = () => {
  setData(newMenuItems)
}
```

This will change `data` from `menuItems` to `newMenuItems`, and it will continue to invoke `.map()` over `newMenuItems` since that is now stored in `data`

Comment: I swear I've tried this way, but I guess something else was the problem. Thank you!